# Selecting nested record on PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have a table in database sql like below, and i want to display it based on id and how many record (generation)

```
+-------------------------------+
|      ID      |    Parent_ID   | 
+-------------------------------+
|      1       |        0       |
+-------------------------------+
|      2       |        1       |
+-------------------------------+
|      3       |        1       |
+-------------------------------+
|      4       |        2       |
+-------------------------------+
|      5       |        2       | 
+-------------------------------+
|      6       |        2       |
+-------------------------------+
|      7       |        2       |
+-------------------------------+
|      8       |        3       | 
+-------------------------------+
|      9       |        5       |
+-------------------------------+
|      10      |        7       |
+-------------------------------+
|      11       |       10      | 
+-------------------------------+
|      12       |       10      | 
.................................
The list goes on..
```

so if i want to select the ID = 2 and record from 1st generation to 4th generation, the result is gonna be like this

```
+-------------------------------+
|      ID      |    Parent_ID   | 
+-------------------------------+
|      2       |        1       |  -> 1st generation
+-------------------------------+
|      4       |        2       |  -> 2nd generation
+-------------------------------+
|      5       |        2       |  -> 2nd generation
+-------------------------------+
|      6       |        2       |  -> 2nd generation
+-------------------------------+
|      7       |        2       |  -> 2nd generation
+-------------------------------+
|      10      |        7       |  -> 3rd generation
+-------------------------------+
|      12       |       10      |  -> 4th generation
.................................
```

the generation is not always from first, so i start select from any generation position, any idea how to do this in php or php laravel using MySQL database?

Comment: How do you specify the generation?

Comment: From the example I understand that you need to order the result by Parent_ID. Is this the case?

Comment: @Anas generation is like starting point to display the n-th record to child-th generation of the record

Comment: @iliaz yes i need to order it based on the first id (input id) and then go to second record that has parent id as same as the first id and then go to record id that has parent id as same as the second record id and then so on til the y-th record(generation)

Comment: On your second table, you have id 1 shown only once. Is this intentional, or you missed it? An why 3rd generation is id 9 and not 8?

Comment: @iliaz i just edited my question, yes that is intentional because  the first generation goes like that

Comment: Might be worth you googling mysql recursion.